# Npath and Cyclomatic complexity using Oclint

Tags: c, compilation, static-analysis, oclint

Can someone please explain me how to get the Npath and Cyclomatic complexity using the Oclint tool? I am currently using the command

./oclint /home/kyriakos/Measurements/base64.c -- -c

and getting as output:

OCLint Report

Summary: TotalFiles=1 FilesWithViolations=1 P1=0 P2=0 P3=3

/home/kyriakos/Measurements/base64.c:18:5: short variable name P3 Variable name with 1 characters is shorter than the threshold of 3

/home/kyriakos/Measurements/base64.c:18:5: short variable name P3 Variable name with 1 characters is shorter than the threshold of 3

/home/kyriakos/Measurements//base64.c:18:5: short variable name P3 Variable name with 1 characters is shorter than the threshold of 3

[OCLint (http://oclint.org) v0.8.1]

Answer (score 1):

OK just figure this out. You need to set the metric parameter to the minimum to force it throw a warning. For example:

./oclint -rc=CYCLOMATIC_COMPLEXITY=1 /home/kyriakos/Measurements/base64.c -- -g

then I get:

/home/kyriakos/base64.c:14:1: high cyclomatic complexity P2 Cyclomatic Complexity Number 7 exceeds limit of 1